# Accidentally formatted the partition which contains my back up

Tags: data-recovery

I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 but I accidentally formatted the Windows partition which contains all my backup. How can I recover data on that partition?

Comment: Have you deleted it? or just formatted it? did you change the partition type?

Answer (score 2):

Use *TestDisk*

it's command line based tool which can recover almost all of your data, even in NTFS partition. I wouldn't use it to recover an OS but media files and documents in the partition should come back. you can even choose what files you want and it's a really powerful tool if you first read the complete instructions

to install *testdisk* and start using it, type these commands into in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
testdisk
```

[Here is the Official step by step guide to use test disk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)